# List comprehension in python with variable assignment

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

Suppose i have the following for loop

```
L=[]
for e in C:
    t=0
    for r in D:
        if r[0]==e:
            t=t+r[2]
    L.append((e,t))
```

To give some more information e is a list, r is a tuple of size 3. I also want each element of L to contain a tuple.

How do i write the following in a list comprehension? I'm unsure as there are variable assignments in the for loop. I'd really appreciate any help! Thanks!!

Answer (score 8):

work it up in reverse.

What is the data to append to `L` ? a `tuple`.
What is this tuple made of? `e` (we have it) and the sum of some terms given a condition.

So without testing I can write:

```
L = [(e,sum(r[2] for r in D if r[0]==e)) for e in C]
```

Comment: There has to be a better answer that does not traverse `D` `len(C)` times but just once. If we just want to translate OP's loop to a comprehension 1-1, it does not get better than this.

Comment: yes, you may be right, but without further test data, it's difficult to see that. it would probably involve generating a dict of some sort to save the inner loop.

Comment: anyway I'm keeping this Q&A for my future training sessions :) a good example of complex loop turned into ... a complex list comprehension :)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis to avoid re-traversing one has to build the index of D first, so that filtering turns into trivial key lookup in a dict.

Answer (score 3):

```
L = [
    (
        e,
        (sum(r[2] for r in D if r[0]==e))
    )
    for e in C
]
```

Comment: There's something going wrong with the parentheses around `sum`…

Comment: not the downvoter, but `sum(r[2])` this can't be correct

Comment: Oops, fixed. The answer above got it right first time :)

Answer (score 3):

This solution might be more complicated and not a *simple list-comprehension* but it is also **more efficient** (O(n) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>)). The reason is that we no longer have go through the entire list `D` for every item `e` we get from `C` but only **once**. As a result, the benefits of this approach scale with increasing size of `D` or `C`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

D = [["A", 0], ["B", 1], ["C", 0], ["D", 2], ["A", 2]]
D.sort(key=itemgetter(0))

glo = {k: sum(f[1] for f in g) for k, g in groupby(D, key=itemgetter(0))}

L = [(e, glo[e]) for e in C]
```